# two condition in same query laravel

Tags: php, laravel

here is what I want
check rows with ( user_id AND member_name)
I have try some other code and in this one I got this error
"message":"mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

```php
$checkData= DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where(DB::table('member_opinions')
        ->where('user_id',$members->user_id)
    )
    ->orWhere( DB::table('member_opinions')
        ->where('member_name',$request->{'committees_name'})
    )
    ->first();
 /* $checkData= DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id',$members->user_id)
    ->orWhere('member_name',$request->{'committees_name'})
    ->first();
 */
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Where do you use mb_strpos() php function? The error message references to that function, but I cannot see it used in the code you pasted into the question.

Comment: yes I haven't use it, and it's only show when I added the query

Comment: Then you may have encountered a bug in laravel...

Comment: maybe, but I'm pretty sure the query is built wrong :)

Comment: Yes, a lot of your query is not built correctly. You don't need to pass in sub queries for each where.

Comment: What exactly is the query you're trying to build?

Comment: If your $members  is collection you need write  ->whereIn('user_id',$members->user_id)

Comment: I want a query with two conditions user_id AND member_name

Comment: it's not a collection it's a string

Comment: Your commented query should actually be correct, though you don't need the braces and quotes for `committees_name`, unless that's a placeholder for a variable. What issue were you having with that one?

Comment: give us more info, like whats the result of $request->all(). tbh that curly braces is only for vars as aynber said. also whats the $members output? just use **dd($request->all(), $members);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$checkData= DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id',$members->user_id)
    ->orWhere('member_name',$request->{'committees_name'})
    ->first();
```

Let me know did it works.

Update:

Try it out if you want and operation

```
$checkData= DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id',$members->user_id)
    ->where('member_name',$request->{'committees_name'})
    ->first();
```

Comment: this doesn't meet what I want, bc it's or :)

Comment: Let me know your query

Comment: I have a specific user id and committees_name there is some other rows with same user id and different committees_name ( if i use your query it will give me all the rows for the  user id  without checking committees_name I gave in the query)

Comment: Oh, i see, just write 'where' instead of 'orWhere', hope you will get your results

Comment: Hey Saied, it would be worth updating your answer to reflect the changes in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of you try to provide object in `where()` function instead of string.
You have to extract your conditions from inner `where()` functions and provide them directly to outer `where()` functions like this:

```
$checkData = DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id', $members->user_id)
    ->orWhere('member_name', $request->{'committees_name'})
    ->first();
```

After that, pay attention on what you want to get. As I can see, you want to use AND condition, but used `orWhere()` function, which will build your query with OR condition. So, you should use `andWhere()` instead:

```
$checkData = DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id', $members->user_id)
    ->andWhere('member_name', $request->{'committees_name'})
    ->first();
```

And finally, let's make your code less dirty:

```
$userId = $members->user_id;
$commiteesName = $request->committees_name;
$checkData = DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->andWhere('member_name', $commiteesName)
    ->first();
```

**UPD**: @user3532758 is right, it is no method called `andWhere()` in Laravel, you should use `where()` instead:

```
$userId = $members->user_id;
$commiteesName = $request->committees_name;
$checkData = DB::table('member_opinions')
    ->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->where('member_name', $commiteesName)
    ->first();
```

Comment: dont think `andWhere` is valid. `where` would suffice.

Comment: "message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::andWhere